# removing all special characters from an email address

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, replace, oracle19c

I have an email column in the table, and I am trying to remove all special characters before "@". If there's a "+" sign I want to remove everything after the "+" sign until "@"

I tried using regexp but the length of the string is not consistent.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'will.cole@gmail.com'      from dual union all
  3     select 'will_cole@hotmail.com'    from dual union all
  4     select 'willcole+kfc@outlook.com' from dual union all
  5     select 'willcole!@gmail.com'      from dual union all
  6     select 'willcole.96@gmail.com'    from dual
  7    )
```

Query:

- 1st expression removes sign `+` and *word* that follows
- 2nd expression removes non-alpanumerics up to the `@` character

---

```
  8  select col,
  9    regexp_replace(col, '(\+\w+)|[^[:alnum:]@]', '') result
 10  from test;

COL                            RESULT
------------------------------ ------------------------------
will.cole@gmail.com            willcole@gmailcom
will_cole@hotmail.com          willcole@hotmailcom
willcole+kfc@outlook.com       willcole@outlookcom
willcole!@gmail.com            willcole@gmailcom
willcole.96@gmail.com          willcole96@gmailcom

SQL>
```